# Angular cant connect to spring boot endpoints in docker compose

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I moved my spring app (backend) and angular app (frontend) to docker compose - all looks works well, but when angular send GET/POST to spring boot gets no reponse.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java

VOLUME /tmp

ADD build/libs/backend.jar spring-boot-app.jar

RUN bash -c 'touch /spring-boot-app.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/spring-boot-app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'


  backend:
    container_name: "backend"
    restart: always
    image: app:latest
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    - mongodb
    ports:
    - 8087:8080

  frontend:
    container_name: "frontend"
    image: frontend:latest
    ports:
    - 4201:4200
```

Dockerfile angular:

```
FROM node:9.6.1

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.1

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --prod
```

My api const:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: "http://backend:8080"
};
```

When I go to localhost:4201 - I can see my frontend, when I go to localhost:8087 I can see my backend and endpoints works well, but Angular doesnt get response:

[image]

For couple of time I'm trying to figure out - I will be grateful for every advice.

Comment: You are exposing port `8087`, so you probably should change the port number here: `apiUrl: "http://backend:8087"`

Comment: I exposing it only to my machine - inside docker should see port 8080 as I did in `ports:
    - 8087:8080`

Comment: Yes, but your browser makes the request to the back-end, not the angular container. The angular container is only hosting the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular application is not running in a **container**, it's served as static files to be run in the **browser**. You have mapped the 8087 port outside the container to the 8080 port inside it, so just use the following URL for the API calls from Angular: `http://<your-machine-or-domain-name>:8087`